# OBS WebSocket disconnects immediately

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, obs

I'm trying to create an app to control OBS, but I was testing to establish a connection with node and it disconnects immediately after running the script. I have the correct port and password and it is allowed through my firewall.

```js
const WebSocket = require('ws');

const obsAddress = 'ws://localhost:4455'; 
const obsPassword = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxx';
const obsSocket = new WebSocket(obsAddress);

obsSocket.on('open', function () {
    console.log('Connected to OBS WebSocket');
    
    const authMessage = {
        "request-type": "GetAuthRequired"
    };
    
    obsSocket.send(JSON.stringify(authMessage));

    obsSocket.on('message', function (data) {
        const message = JSON.parse(data);
        if (message['status'] === 'error') {
            console.error('Error:', message['error']);
        } else {
            console.log('Success:', message);
        }
    });
});

obsSocket.on('error', function (error) {
    console.error('WebSocket Error:', error);
});

obsSocket.on('close', function () {
    console.log('Connection to OBS WebSocket closed');
});
```

And here's the terminal log after using 'node obs.js'

```
Connected to OBS WebSocket
Success: {
  d: {
    authentication: {
      challenge: 'd506cAvkZXWs5kkfrJpm0+DUO1fGEr0JjxwRXQYn16w=',
      salt: 'binILkPgQrBli3KGSM/bRf4spegQQ3XRsMO7jRgJcwc='
    },
    obsWebSocketVersion: '5.3.4',
    rpcVersion: 1
  },
  op: 0
}
Connection to OBS WebSocket closed
```

And the OBS log:

> 11:55:29.709: [obs-websocket] [WebSocketServer::onClose] WebSocket client [::ffff:127.0.0.1]:59407 has disconnected with code 4010 and reason: You appear to be attempting to connect with the pre-5.0.0 plugin protocol. Check to make sure your client is updated.

I'd like the connection to stay so I'm able to communicate and send requests or messages to OBS WebSocket to be able to build the app.

Comment: Are you trying to create a WebSocket server?

Comment: Do you keep the server running somehow? If so, have you tried sending keep alive messages to the socket?

Comment: Looks okay at a cursory glance. What do the logs from OBS say?

Comment: Here's some information that may be the leading cause of the issue from my OBS log:

11:55:29.709: [obs-websocket] [WebSocketServer::onClose] WebSocket client `[::ffff:127.0.0.1]:59407` has disconnected with code `4010` and reason: You appear to be attempting to connect with the pre-5.0.0 plugin protocol. Check to make sure your client is updated.

Answer (score -1):

Based on the error message in the OBS log file, you are attempting to communicate with OBS via an old protocol that is not supported by your newer version of OBS. This change to protocol version 5 appears to have happened somewhere around mid-2022 with OBS version 28.

Instead of using raw WebSockets, there is an `obs-websocket-js` library that you can install via NPM. Documentation for this is available here: [obs-websocket-js](https://github.com/obs-websocket-community-projects/obs-websocket-js) The first non-beta version of this was released on [July 4, 2022](https://github.com/obs-websocket-community-projects/obs-websocket-js/releases). The project link includes sample setup code that appears very similar to your code so it should be relatively easy to migrate.

I do not have or use OBS and so cannot test any of this, but if you have an existing program you are trying to update there are also `compat` versions of `obs-websocket-js` available for version OBS versions >= OBS 28 using protocol version 4 (if I'm understanding this correctly, which also implies an OBS setting somewhere). These can be downloaded from the OBS-websocket project releases page [available here on github](https://github.com/obsproject/obs-websocket/releases).